# Duplicate entries when trying to seed image on ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to the Ruby on Rails ecosystem so might question might be really trivial.

I have set up an Active Storage on one of my model

```rb
class Sedcard < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :photos
end
```

And I simply want to seed data with `Faker` in it like so:

```rb
require 'faker'

Sedcard.destroy_all
20.times do |_i|
  sedcard = Sedcard.create!(
    showname: Faker::Name.female_first_name,
    description: Faker::Lorem.paragraph(10),
    phone: Faker::PhoneNumber.cell_phone,
    birthdate: Faker::Date.birthday(18, 40),
    gender: Sedcard.genders[:female],
    is_active: Faker::Boolean.boolean
  )

  index = Faker::Number.unique.between(1, 99)
  image = open("https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/#{index}.jpg")
  sedcard.photos.attach(io: image, filename: "avatar#{index}.jpg", content_type: 'image/png')
end
```

The problem is that some of these records end up with multiple photos attached to them, could be 5 or 10.

Most records are seeded well, they have only one photo associated, but the ones with multiple photos all follow the same pattern, they are all seeded with the exact same images.

Comment: Could it be that the ActiveStorage blobs table is not cleaned when you run `Sedcard.destroy_all`? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#discarding-files-stored-during-system-tests

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem myself.

I was using UUID as my model's primary key which is not natively compatible with ActiveStorage. Thus, I more or less followed the instructions [here](https://www.wrburgess.com/posts/2018-02-03-1.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to purge the attachments.

Try adding this snippet before destroyingthe `Sedcard`'s

```
Sedcard.all.each{ |s| s.photos.purge }
```

Ref: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#removing-files